# Why `print key[0]` produce different results

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
.... #code
from ast import literal_eval
from collections import defaultdict
nLedgers=[['173', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['183', '1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['184', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['194', '1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['195', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['205', '1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['206', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['216', '1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['217', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['227', '1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['228', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['238', '1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['239', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['249', '1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['250', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['260', '1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['261', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['271', '1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['272', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['282', '1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['283', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['293', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['294', '1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['304', '1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['305', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['315', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['316', '1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['326', '1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['327', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['337', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['338', '1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['348', '1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['349', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['359', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['360', '1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['370', '1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['371', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['381', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['382', '1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['392', '1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['436', '-1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['446', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['447', '-1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['457', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['458', '-1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['468', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['469', '-1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['479', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['480', '-1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['490', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['491', '-1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['501', '-1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['502', '-1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['512', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['513', '-1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['523', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['524', '-1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['534', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['535', '-1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['545', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['546', '-1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['556', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['557', '-1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['567', '-1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['568', '-1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['578', '-1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['579', '-1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['589', '-1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['590', '-1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['600', '-1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['687', '0.', '2000.', '0.'], ['697', '1000.', '2000.', '0.'], ['698', '0.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['708', '1000.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['709', '0.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['719', '1000.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['720', '0.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['730', '1000.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['731', '0.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['741', '1000.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['742', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['752', '0.', '2000.', '0.'], ['753', '1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['763', '1000.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['764', '1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['774', '1000.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['775', '1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['785', '1000.', '2000.', '0.'], ['786', '1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['796', '1000.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['797', '1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['807', '1000.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['808', '-1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['818', '-1000.', '2000.', '0.'], ['819', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['829', '0.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['830', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['840', '0.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['841', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['851', '0.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['852', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['862', '0.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['863', '-1000.', '2000.', '0.'], ['873', '0.', '2000.', '0.'], ['874', '-1000.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['884', '0.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['885', '-1000.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['895', '0.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['896', '-1000.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['906', '0.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['907', '-1000.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['917', '0.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['918', '-1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['928', '-1000.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['929', '-1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['939', '-1000.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['940', '-1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['950', '-1000.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['951', '-1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['961', '-1000.', '2000.', '4000.']]
nodes=[['1', '0.', '0.', '-100.'], ['2', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['3', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['4', '0.', '0.', '4100.'], ['5', '0.', '0.', '100.'], ['6', '0.', '0.', '200.'], ['7', '0.', '0.', '300.'], ['8', '0.', '0.', '400.'], ['9', '0.', '0.', '500.'], ['10', '0.', '0.', '600.'], ['11', '0.', '0.', '700.'], ['12', '0.', '0.', '800.'], ['13', '0.', '0.', '900.'], ['14', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['15', '0.', '0.', '1100.'], ['16', '0.', '0.', '1200.'], ['17', '0.', '0.', '1300.'], ['18', '0.', '0.', '1400.'], ['19', '0.', '0.', '1500.'], ['20', '0.', '0.', '1600.'], ['21', '0.', '0.', '1700.'], ['22', '0.', '0.', '1800.'], ['23', '0.', '0.', '1900.'], ['24', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['25', '0.', '0.', '2100.'], ['26', '0.', '0.', '2200.'], ['27', '0.', '0.', '2300.'], ['28', '0.', '0.', '2400.'], ['29', '0.', '0.', '2500.'], ['30', '0.', '0.', '2600.'], ['31', '0.', '0.', '2700.'], ['32', '0.', '0.', '2800.'], ['33', '0.', '0.', '2900.'], ['34', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['35', '0.', '0.', '3100.'], ['36', '0.', '0.', '3200.'], ['37', '0.', '0.', '3300.'], ['38', '0.', '0.', '3400.'], ['39', '0.', '0.', '3500.'], ['40', '0.', '0.', '3600.'], ['41', '0.', '0.', '3700.'], ['42', '0.', '0.', '3800.'], ['43', '0.', '0.', '3900.'], ['44', '0.', '1000.', '-100.'], ['45', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['46', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['47', '0.', '1000.', '4100.'], ['48', '0.', '1000.', '100.'], ['49', '0.', '1000.', '200.'], ['50', '0.', '1000.', '300.'], ['51', '0.', '1000.', '400.'], ['52', '0.', '1000.', '500.'], ['53', '0.', '1000.', '600.'], ['54', '0.', '1000.', '700.'], ['55', '0.', '1000.', '800.'], ['56', '0.', '1000.', '900.'], ['57', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['58', '0.', '1000.', '1100.'], ['59', '0.', '1000.', '1200.'], ['60', '0.', '1000.', '1300.'], ['61', '0.', '1000.', '1400.'], ['62', '0.', '1000.', '1500.'], ['63', '0.', '1000.', '1600.'], ['64', '0.', '1000.', '1700.'], ['65', '0.', '1000.', '1800.'], ['66', '0.', '1000.', '1900.'], ['67', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['68', '0.', '1000.', '2100.'], ['69', '0.', '1000.', '2200.'], ['70', '0.', '1000.', '2300.'], ['71', '0.', '1000.', '2400.'], ['72', '0.', '1000.', '2500.'], ['73', '0.', '1000.', '2600.'], ['74', '0.', '1000.', '2700.'], ['75', '0.', '1000.', '2800.'], ['76', '0.', '1000.', '2900.'], ['77', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['78', '0.', '1000.', '3100.'], ['79', '0.', '1000.', '3200.'], ['80', '0.', '1000.', '3300.'], ['81', '0.', '1000.', '3400.'], ['82', '0.', '1000.', '3500.'], ['83', '0.', '1000.', '3600.'], ['84', '0.', '1000.', '3700.'], ['85', '0.', '1000.', '3800.'], ['86', '0.', '1000.', '3900.'], ['87', '1000.', '0.', '-100.'], ['88', '1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['89', '1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['90', '1000.', '0.', '4100.'], ['91', '1000.', '0.', '100.'], ['92', '1000.', '0.', '200.'], ['93', '1000.', '0.', '300.'], ['94', '1000.', '0.', '400.'], ['95', '1000.', '0.', '500.'], ['96', '1000.', '0.', '600.'], ['97', '1000.', '0.', '700.'], ['98', '1000.', '0.', '800.'], ['99', '1000.', '0.', '900.'], ['100', '1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['101', '1000.', '0.', '1100.'], ['102', '1000.', '0.', '1200.'], ['103', '1000.', '0.', '1300.'], ['104', '1000.', '0.', '1400.'], ['105', '1000.', '0.', '1500.'], ['106', '1000.', '0.', '1600.'], ['107', '1000.', '0.', '1700.'], ['108', '1000.', '0.', '1800.'], ['109', '1000.', '0.', '1900.'], ['110', '1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['111', '1000.', '0.', '2100.'], ['112', '1000.', '0.', '2200.'], ['113', '1000.', '0.', '2300.'], ['114', '1000.', '0.', '2400.'], ['115', '1000.', '0.', '2500.'], ['116', '1000.', '0.', '2600.'], ['117', '1000.', '0.', '2700.'], ['118', '1000.', '0.', '2800.'], ['119', '1000.', '0.', '2900.'], ['120', '1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['121', '1000.', '0.', '3100.'], ['122', '1000.', '0.', '3200.'], ['123', '1000.', '0.', '3300.'], ['124', '1000.', '0.', '3400.'], ['125', '1000.', '0.', '3500.'], ['126', '1000.', '0.', '3600.'], ['127', '1000.', '0.', '3700.'], ['128', '1000.', '0.', '3800.'], ['129', '1000.', '0.', '3900.'], ['130', '1000.', '1000.', '-100.'], ['131', '1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['132', '1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['133', '1000.', '1000.', '4100.'], ['134', '1000.', '1000.', '100.'], ['135', '1000.', '1000.', '200.'], ['136', '1000.', '1000.', '300.'], ['137', '1000.', '1000.', '400.'], ['138', '1000.', '1000.', '500.'], ['139', '1000.', '1000.', '600.'], ['140', '1000.', '1000.', '700.'], ['141', '1000.', '1000.', '800.'], ['142', '1000.', '1000.', '900.'], ['143', '1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['144', '1000.', '1000.', '1100.'], ['145', '1000.', '1000.', '1200.'], ['146', '1000.', '1000.', '1300.'], ['147', '1000.', '1000.', '1400.'], ['148', '1000.', '1000.', '1500.'], ['149', '1000.', '1000.', '1600.'], ['150', '1000.', '1000.', '1700.'], ['151', '1000.', '1000.', '1800.'], ['152', '1000.', '1000.', '1900.'], ['153', '1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['154', '1000.', '1000.', '2100.'], ['155', '1000.', '1000.', '2200.'], ['156', '1000.', '1000.', '2300.'], ['157', '1000.', '1000.', '2400.'], ['158', '1000.', '1000.', '2500.'], ['159', '1000.', '1000.', '2600.'], ['160', '1000.', '1000.', '2700.'], ['161', '1000.', '1000.', '2800.'], ['162', '1000.', '1000.', '2900.'], ['163', '1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['164', '1000.', '1000.', '3100.'], ['165', '1000.', '1000.', '3200.'], ['166', '1000.', '1000.', '3300.'], ['167', '1000.', '1000.', '3400.'], ['168', '1000.', '1000.', '3500.'], ['169', '1000.', '1000.', '3600.'], ['170', '1000.', '1000.', '3700.'], ['171', '1000.', '1000.', '3800.'], ['172', '1000.', '1000.', '3900.'], ['173', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['174', '100.', '0.', '0.'], ['175', '200.', '0.', '0.'], ['176', '300.', '0.', '0.'], ['177', '400.', '0.', '0.'], ['178', '500.', '0.', '0.'], ['179', '600.', '0.', '0.'], ['180', '700.', '0.', '0.'], ['181', '800.', '0.', '0.'], ['182', '900.', '0.', '0.'], ['183', '1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['184', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['185', '100.', '1000.', '0.'], ['186', '200.', '1000.', '0.'], ['187', '300.', '1000.', '0.'], ['188', '400.', '1000.', '0.'], ['189', '500.', '1000.', '0.'], ['190', '600.', '1000.', '0.'], ['191', '700.', '1000.', '0.'], ['192', '800.', '1000.', '0.'], ['193', '900.', '1000.', '0.'], ['194', '1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['195', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['196', '100.', '0.', '1000.'], ['197', '200.', '0.', '1000.'], ['198', '300.', '0.', '1000.'], ['199', '400.', '0.', '1000.'], ['200', '500.', '0.', '1000.'], ['201', '600.', '0.', '1000.'], ['202', '700.', '0.', '1000.'], ['203', '800.', '0.', '1000.'], ['204', '900.', '0.', '1000.'], ['205', '1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['206', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['207', '100.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['208', '200.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['209', '300.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['210', '400.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['211', '500.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['212', '600.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['213', '700.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['214', '800.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['215', '900.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['216', '1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['217', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['218', '100.', '0.', '2000.'], ['219', '200.', '0.', '2000.'], ['220', '300.', '0.', '2000.'], ['221', '400.', '0.', '2000.'], ['222', '500.', '0.', '2000.'], ['223', '600.', '0.', '2000.'], ['224', '700.', '0.', '2000.'], ['225', '800.', '0.', '2000.'], ['226', '900.', '0.', '2000.'], ['227', '1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['228', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['229', '100.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['230', '200.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['231', '300.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['232', '400.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['233', '500.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['234', '600.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['235', '700.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['236', '800.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['237', '900.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['238', '1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['239', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['240', '100.', '0.', '3000.'], ['241', '200.', '0.', '3000.'], ['242', '300.', '0.', '3000.'], ['243', '400.', '0.', '3000.'], ['244', '500.', '0.', '3000.'], ['245', '600.', '0.', '3000.'], ['246', '700.', '0.', '3000.'], ['247', '800.', '0.', '3000.'], ['248', '900.', '0.', '3000.'], ['249', '1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['250', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['251', '100.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['252', '200.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['253', '300.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['254', '400.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['255', '500.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['256', '600.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['257', '700.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['258', '800.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['259', '900.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['260', '1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['261', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['262', '100.', '0.', '4000.'], ['263', '200.', '0.', '4000.'], ['264', '300.', '0.', '4000.'], ['265', '400.', '0.', '4000.'], ['266', '500.', '0.', '4000.'], ['267', '600.', '0.', '4000.'], ['268', '700.', '0.', '4000.'], ['269', '800.', '0.', '4000.'], ['270', '900.', '0.', '4000.'], ['271', '1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['272', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['273', '100.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['274', '200.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['275', '300.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['276', '400.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['277', '500.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['278', '600.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['279', '700.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['280', '800.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['281', '900.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['282', '1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['283', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['284', '0.', '100.', '0.'], ['285', '0.', '200.', '0.'], ['286', '0.', '300.', '0.'], ['287', '0.', '400.', '0.'], ['288', '0.', '500.', '0.'], ['289', '0.', '600.', '0.'], ['290', '0.', '700.', '0.'], ['291', '0.', '800.', '0.'], ['292', '0.', '900.', '0.'], ['293', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['294', '1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['295', '1000.', '100.', '0.'], ['296', '1000.', '200.', '0.'], ['297', '1000.', '300.', '0.'], ['298', '1000.', '400.', '0.'], ['299', '1000.', '500.', '0.'], ['300', '1000.', '600.', '0.'], ['301', '1000.', '700.', '0.'], ['302', '1000.', '800.', '0.'], ['303', '1000.', '900.', '0.'], ['304', '1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['305', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['306', '0.', '100.', '1000.'], ['307', '0.', '200.', '1000.'], ['308', '0.', '300.', '1000.'], ['309', '0.', '400.', '1000.'], ['310', '0.', '500.', '1000.'], ['311', '0.', '600.', '1000.'], ['312', '0.', '700.', '1000.'], ['313', '0.', '800.', '1000.'], ['314', '0.', '900.', '1000.'], ['315', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['316', '1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['317', '1000.', '100.', '1000.'], ['318', '1000.', '200.', '1000.'], ['319', '1000.', '300.', '1000.'], ['320', '1000.', '400.', '1000.'], ['321', '1000.', '500.', '1000.'], ['322', '1000.', '600.', '1000.'], ['323', '1000.', '700.', '1000.'], ['324', '1000.', '800.', '1000.'], ['325', '1000.', '900.', '1000.'], ['326', '1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['327', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['328', '0.', '100.', '2000.'], ['329', '0.', '200.', '2000.'], ['330', '0.', '300.', '2000.'], ['331', '0.', '400.', '2000.'], ['332', '0.', '500.', '2000.'], ['333', '0.', '600.', '2000.'], ['334', '0.', '700.', '2000.'], ['335', '0.', '800.', '2000.'], ['336', '0.', '900.', '2000.'], ['337', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['338', '1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['339', '1000.', '100.', '2000.'], ['340', '1000.', '200.', '2000.'], ['341', '1000.', '300.', '2000.'], ['342', '1000.', '400.', '2000.'], ['343', '1000.', '500.', '2000.'], ['344', '1000.', '600.', '2000.'], ['345', '1000.', '700.', '2000.'], ['346', '1000.', '800.', '2000.'], ['347', '1000.', '900.', '2000.'], ['348', '1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['349', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['350', '0.', '100.', '3000.'], ['351', '0.', '200.', '3000.'], ['352', '0.', '300.', '3000.'], ['353', '0.', '400.', '3000.'], ['354', '0.', '500.', '3000.'], ['355', '0.', '600.', '3000.'], ['356', '0.', '700.', '3000.'], ['357', '0.', '800.', '3000.'], ['358', '0.', '900.', '3000.'], ['359', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['360', '1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['361', '1000.', '100.', '3000.'], ['362', '1000.', '200.', '3000.'], ['363', '1000.', '300.', '3000.'], ['364', '1000.', '400.', '3000.'], ['365', '1000.', '500.', '3000.'], ['366', '1000.', '600.', '3000.'], ['367', '1000.', '700.', '3000.'], ['368', '1000.', '800.', '3000.'], ['369', '1000.', '900.', '3000.'], ['370', '1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['371', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['372', '0.', '100.', '4000.'], ['373', '0.', '200.', '4000.'], ['374', '0.', '300.', '4000.'], ['375', '0.', '400.', '4000.'], ['376', '0.', '500.', '4000.'], ['377', '0.', '600.', '4000.'], ['378', '0.', '700.', '4000.'], ['379', '0.', '800.', '4000.'], ['380', '0.', '900.', '4000.'], ['381', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['382', '1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['383', '1000.', '100.', '4000.'], ['384', '1000.', '200.', '4000.'], ['385', '1000.', '300.', '4000.'], ['386', '1000.', '400.', '4000.'], ['387', '1000.', '500.', '4000.'], ['388', '1000.', '600.', '4000.'], ['389', '1000.', '700.', '4000.'], ['390', '1000.', '800.', '4000.'], ['391', '1000.', '900.', '4000.'], ['392', '1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['393', '-1000.', '0.', '-100.'], ['394', '-1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['395', '-1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['396', '-1000.', '0.', '4100.'], ['397', '-1000.', '0.', '100.'], ['398', '-1000.', '0.', '200.'], ['399', '-1000.', '0.', '300.'], ['400', '-1000.', '0.', '400.'], ['401', '-1000.', '0.', '500.'], ['402', '-1000.', '0.', '600.'], ['403', '-1000.', '0.', '700.'], ['404', '-1000.', '0.', '800.'], ['405', '-1000.', '0.', '900.'], ['406', '-1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['407', '-1000.', '0.', '1100.'], ['408', '-1000.', '0.', '1200.'], ['409', '-1000.', '0.', '1300.'], ['410', '-1000.', '0.', '1400.'], ['411', '-1000.', '0.', '1500.'], ['412', '-1000.', '0.', '1600.'], ['413', '-1000.', '0.', '1700.'], ['414', '-1000.', '0.', '1800.'], ['415', '-1000.', '0.', '1900.'], ['416', '-1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['417', '-1000.', '0.', '2100.'], ['418', '-1000.', '0.', '2200.'], ['419', '-1000.', '0.', '2300.'], ['420', '-1000.', '0.', '2400.'], ['421', '-1000.', '0.', '2500.'], ['422', '-1000.', '0.', '2600.'], ['423', '-1000.', '0.', '2700.'], ['424', '-1000.', '0.', '2800.'], ['425', '-1000.', '0.', '2900.'], ['426', '-1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['427', '-1000.', '0.', '3100.'], ['428', '-1000.', '0.', '3200.'], ['429', '-1000.', '0.', '3300.'], ['430', '-1000.', '0.', '3400.'], ['431', '-1000.', '0.', '3500.'], ['432', '-1000.', '0.', '3600.'], ['433', '-1000.', '0.', '3700.'], ['434', '-1000.', '0.', '3800.'], ['435', '-1000.', '0.', '3900.'], ['436', '-1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['437', '-900.', '0.', '0.'], ['438', '-800.', '0.', '0.'], ['439', '-700.', '0.', '0.'], ['440', '-600.', '0.', '0.'], ['441', '-500.', '0.', '0.'], ['442', '-400.', '0.', '0.'], ['443', '-300.', '0.', '0.'], ['444', '-200.', '0.', '0.'], ['445', '-100.', '0.', '0.'], ['446', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['447', '-1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['448', '-900.', '1000.', '0.'], ['449', '-800.', '1000.', '0.'], ['450', '-700.', '1000.', '0.'], ['451', '-600.', '1000.', '0.'], ['452', '-500.', '1000.', '0.'], ['453', '-400.', '1000.', '0.'], ['454', '-300.', '1000.', '0.'], ['455', '-200.', '1000.', '0.'], ['456', '-100.', '1000.', '0.'], ['457', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['458', '-1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['459', '-900.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['460', '-800.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['461', '-700.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['462', '-600.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['463', '-500.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['464', '-400.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['465', '-300.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['466', '-200.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['467', '-100.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['468', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['469', '-1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['470', '-900.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['471', '-800.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['472', '-700.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['473', '-600.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['474', '-500.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['475', '-400.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['476', '-300.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['477', '-200.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['478', '-100.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['479', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['480', '-1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['481', '-900.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['482', '-800.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['483', '-700.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['484', '-600.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['485', '-500.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['486', '-400.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['487', '-300.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['488', '-200.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['489', '-100.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['490', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['491', '-1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['492', '-1000.', '100.', '0.'], ['493', '-1000.', '200.', '0.'], ['494', '-1000.', '300.', '0.'], ['495', '-1000.', '400.', '0.'], ['496', '-1000.', '500.', '0.'], ['497', '-1000.', '600.', '0.'], ['498', '-1000.', '700.', '0.'], ['499', '-1000.', '800.', '0.'], ['500', '-1000.', '900.', '0.'], ['501', '-1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['502', '-1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['503', '-900.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['504', '-800.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['505', '-700.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['506', '-600.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['507', '-500.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['508', '-400.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['509', '-300.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['510', '-200.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['511', '-100.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['512', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['513', '-1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['514', '-900.', '0.', '1000.'], ['515', '-800.', '0.', '1000.'], ['516', '-700.', '0.', '1000.'], ['517', '-600.', '0.', '1000.'], ['518', '-500.', '0.', '1000.'], ['519', '-400.', '0.', '1000.'], ['520', '-300.', '0.', '1000.'], ['521', '-200.', '0.', '1000.'], ['522', '-100.', '0.', '1000.'], ['523', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['524', '-1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['525', '-900.', '0.', '2000.'], ['526', '-800.', '0.', '2000.'], ['527', '-700.', '0.', '2000.'], ['528', '-600.', '0.', '2000.'], ['529', '-500.', '0.', '2000.'], ['530', '-400.', '0.', '2000.'], ['531', '-300.', '0.', '2000.'], ['532', '-200.', '0.', '2000.'], ['533', '-100.', '0.', '2000.'], ['534', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['535', '-1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['536', '-900.', '0.', '3000.'], ['537', '-800.', '0.', '3000.'], ['538', '-700.', '0.', '3000.'], ['539', '-600.', '0.', '3000.'], ['540', '-500.', '0.', '3000.'], ['541', '-400.', '0.', '3000.'], ['542', '-300.', '0.', '3000.'], ['543', '-200.', '0.', '3000.'], ['544', '-100.', '0.', '3000.'], ['545', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['546', '-1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['547', '-900.', '0.', '4000.'], ['548', '-800.', '0.', '4000.'], ['549', '-700.', '0.', '4000.'], ['550', '-600.', '0.', '4000.'], ['551', '-500.', '0.', '4000.'], ['552', '-400.', '0.', '4000.'], ['553', '-300.', '0.', '4000.'], ['554', '-200.', '0.', '4000.'], ['555', '-100.', '0.', '4000.'], ['556', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['557', '-1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['558', '-1000.', '100.', '1000.'], ['559', '-1000.', '200.', '1000.'], ['560', '-1000.', '300.', '1000.'], ['561', '-1000.', '400.', '1000.'], ['562', '-1000.', '500.', '1000.'], ['563', '-1000.', '600.', '1000.'], ['564', '-1000.', '700.', '1000.'], ['565', '-1000.', '800.', '1000.'], ['566', '-1000.', '900.', '1000.'], ['567', '-1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['568', '-1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['569', '-1000.', '100.', '3000.'], ['570', '-1000.', '200.', '3000.'], ['571', '-1000.', '300.', '3000.'], ['572', '-1000.', '400.', '3000.'], ['573', '-1000.', '500.', '3000.'], ['574', '-1000.', '600.', '3000.'], ['575', '-1000.', '700.', '3000.'], ['576', '-1000.', '800.', '3000.'], ['577', '-1000.', '900.', '3000.'], ['578', '-1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['579', '-1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['580', '-1000.', '100.', '2000.'], ['581', '-1000.', '200.', '2000.'], ['582', '-1000.', '300.', '2000.'], ['583', '-1000.', '400.', '2000.'], ['584', '-1000.', '500.', '2000.'], ['585', '-1000.', '600.', '2000.'], ['586', '-1000.', '700.', '2000.'], ['587', '-1000.', '800.', '2000.'], ['588', '-1000.', '900.', '2000.'], ['589', '-1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['590', '-1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['591', '-1000.', '100.', '4000.'], ['592', '-1000.', '200.', '4000.'], ['593', '-1000.', '300.', '4000.'], ['594', '-1000.', '400.', '4000.'], ['595', '-1000.', '500.', '4000.'], ['596', '-1000.', '600.', '4000.'], ['597', '-1000.', '700.', '4000.'], ['598', '-1000.', '800.', '4000.'], ['599', '-1000.', '900.', '4000.'], ['600', '-1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['601', '-1000.', '1000.', '-100.'], ['602', '-1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['603', '-1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['604', '-1000.', '1000.', '4100.'], ['605', '-1000.', '1000.', '100.'], ['606', '-1000.', '1000.', '200.'], ['607', '-1000.', '1000.', '300.'], ['608', '-1000.', '1000.', '400.'], ['609', '-1000.', '1000.', '500.'], ['610', '-1000.', '1000.', '600.'], ['611', '-1000.', '1000.', '700.'], ['612', '-1000.', '1000.', '800.'], ['613', '-1000.', '1000.', '900.'], ['614', '-1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['615', '-1000.', '1000.', '1100.'], ['616', '-1000.', '1000.', '1200.'], ['617', '-1000.', '1000.', '1300.'], ['618', '-1000.', '1000.', '1400.'], ['619', '-1000.', '1000.', '1500.'], ['620', '-1000.', '1000.', '1600.'], ['621', '-1000.', '1000.', '1700.'], ['622', '-1000.', '1000.', '1800.'], ['623', '-1000.', '1000.', '1900.']]
nLedgers=[[literal_eval(x) for x in item] for item in nLedgers] #transform list of strings to list of floats
nodes=[[literal_eval(x) for x in item] for item in nodes]
dic1=defaultdict(list) #dictionary of X and Y pairs
dic2=defaultdict(list) #dictionary of X and Z pairs

for id,x,y,z in nLedgers:
    dic2[(x,z)].append((id,y))
for key in dic2:
    dic2[key].sort( key=lambda x:float(x[1]) )
for key in dic2:
    print key[0] #output 1

print "-"*30

for i,row in enumerate(nodes):  #same X, different Y
    id,x,y,z=row
    y_levels=[item[1] for item in dic2[(x,z)]]
    z_levels=[item[1] for item in dic1[(x,y)]]
    for k,l in zip(y_levels,y_levels[1:]):
        for key in dic2:
            print key[0] #output 2
```

Output 2 should be a multiple of output 1. Results are given in  http://ideone.com/CDhlsl. Differences occur at the end of output 2.

Why is there a difference in the ouput 2?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: `dic1`is very similar to `dic2`, see EDIT

Comment: Are the bodies of the first two loops indented?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Spyder and tab to ident the loops.

Comment: list and id are built-in names your better not use them for variables. As a result you may have unexpected behavior.

Comment: @singer: I've changed `id` to `nodeID` but `defaultdict(list)` I cannot change. If I use `defaultdict(something else)` it gives me an error. However, the results are the same with `nodeID`.

Comment: There is some illegal indentation here. For example, `dic1[(x,y)].append((id,z))` is a line that would prevent this program from running.

Comment: `defaultdict(list)` is probably using the actual builtin function.  There is nothing wrong with that usage, despite singer's objection.

Comment: Please provide an actual runnable (stripped-down) sample. It's very hard to debug incomplete fragments of complex code. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: Meanwhile, can you tell us (or print out, if you don't know) what's in `dic2.keys()` before the two output loops? And please explain why you expect output2 to match output1. I can see expecting it to be multiple repetitions of -1000, 0, and 1000 instead of a variety of different values, but it wouldn't be exactly the same as output 1 unless the two outer loops only run once each…

Comment: And real question is WHY(?!) are you expecting output to be the same. I cant get what you are trying to achieve with this code, but output-1 loops len(dic2) times, and out-2 runs len(dic2)*min(len(dic1),len(dic2)) times. Could you give us an idea about the problem you are trying to solve? I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: I ran this this code based on the data from your prevoius question, and I am getting a correct output. http://ideone.com/CDhlsl

Comment: @abarnert: True, `output 2` should be a multiple of `output 1`, but the problem is that `output 2` is a variety of values.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: If you look at the end of the results in ideone you will find `300.0
0.0
1000.0
1000.0
-1000.0
0.0
900.0
400.0
0.0
1000.0
0.0
800.0
1000.0
-1000.0
1000.0
0.0
0.0
300.0
0.0
100.0
0.0
1000.0
600.0
1000.0
500.0
0.0
1000.0
0.0
1000.0
1000.` So it contains values that are not part of `output 1`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
for i,row in enumerate(nodes):  #same X, different Y
```

Your comment suggests that `nodes` and `nLedgers` have the same X values but different Y values in the row.  But they don't:

```
>>> sorted(set(x for i, x, y, z in nLedgers))
[-1000.0, 0.0, 1000.0]
>>> sorted(set(x for i, x, y, z in nodes))
[-1000.0, -900.0, -800.0, -700.0, -600.0, -500.0, -400.0, -300.0, -200.0, -100.0, 0.0, 100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0, 500.0, 600.0, 700.0, 800.0, 900.0, 1000.0]
```

So, after the first loop, dic2 winds up with three distinct first elements of the keys:

```
>>> {k[0] for k in first_d2_saved}
set([0.0, 1000.0, -1000.0])
```

And in the second loop, when you build `y_levels`:

```
y_levels=[item[1] for item in dic2[(x,z)]]
```

you try to access the key `(x, z)`.  For any pair that doesn't exist -- for any `x` in `nodes` not in `nLedgers` -- you create an empty list as the value associated with that key, so the iteration succeeds on an empty list, but now `dic2` has more keys, and thus more new `key[0]` values.  And indeed, the "new" keys all have empty values:

```
>>> sorted({(k[0], tuple(v)) for k,v in dic2.items() if k[0] not in {-1000,0,1000}})
[(-900.0, ()), (-800.0, ()), (-700.0, ()), (-600.0, ()), (-500.0, ()), (-400.0, ()), (-300.0, ()), (-200.0, ()), (-100.0, ()), (100.0, ()), (200.0, ()), (300.0, ()), (400.0, ()), (500.0, ()), (600.0, ()), (700.0, ()), (800.0, ()), (900.0, ())]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The comment `#same X, different Y` is just a help for me to know what is the objective of this part of the code. It relates to the part of `nodes` which have the same `X` and `Z`. `nLedgers` has reference values of `X`, which correspond to control points that will be used to work with the values of `nodes`. I'll study your next comments.